# ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot pie chart, but I get ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'...and I dont understand why, because I have the same length... the error is point to the color. Can u help me?

```py
@widgets.interact(
    team1=["Argentina","Austria","Belgium","Brazil","Bulgaria","Chile","Czechoslovakia","England",
           "France","Germany","Hungary","Italy","Korea Republic","Mexico","Netherlands","Paraguay",
           "Poland","Portugal","Russia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Uruguay","USA","Yugoslavia"],)

def teams_performance(team1="Austria"):
    lst = [team1]
    length = len(team1)
    qtr = mat_new[mat_new["team"].isin(lst)]

    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

    for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(team1,range(length)) : 
        plt.subplot(221)
        lab = ["wins","draws","loses"]
        plt.pie(qtr[qtr["team"] == i][lab].values.ravel(),
                explode = None,
                labels  = lab , 
                autopct = "%1.0f%%",
                shadow  = True,
                wedgeprops = {"linewidth":3.5,"edgecolor":"white"},
                colors  = ["lawngreen","royalblue","tomato"],)

    circ = plt.Circle((0,0),.7,color="white")
    plt.gca().add_artist(circ)

    plt.title(i,color="navy",fontsize=14)
```

Here is the problem...

```py
     20                 shadow  = True,
     21                 wedgeprops = {"linewidth":3.5,"edgecolor":"white"},
---> 22                 colors  = ["lawngreen","royalblue","tomato"],)
     23 
     24     circ = plt.Circle((0,0),.7,color="white")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

Comment: Can you please post the data? What is the length of  `qtr[qtr["team"] == i][lab].values.ravel()`. It looks like you are plotting one point at a time. Also `len(team1)` will return `7`, which means that your `itertools.zip_longest()` will not create what you expect I guess.

Comment: `mat_new = matches_played.merge(lst,left_on="team",right_on="index",how="left")
mat_new = mat_new.merge(win,left_on="team",right_on="index",how="left")
mat_new = mat_new[["team","matches","lost_team","win_team"]]
mat_new = mat_new.fillna(0)
mat_new["win_team"] = mat_new["win_team"].astype(int)
mat_new["draws"]    = (mat_new["matches"]) - (mat_new["lost_team"] + mat_new["win_team"])
mat_new = mat_new.merge(total_goals,left_on="team",right_on="team",how="left")
mat_new = mat_new.rename(columns={"win_team":"wins","lost_team":"loses"})`